# Jenkins can't find files on the hard drive when build is executing

Tags: jenkins

I'm executing a script using Jenkins. I'm receiving the following error:

- 'scriptless-cli' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.

this ^^^^ is an executable that can be found on my C hardrive, I can execute this command through cmd interface on my windows 10 machine and it works as expected.

I've added the console output as well as screen shots of my environment below.

Started by user Stephen Penn
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins.jenkins\workspace\Perfecto Scriptless
Creating Tunnel Id........!
C:\Perfecto-Connect-windows64\perfectoconnect64.exe start -c demo.perfectomobile.com -s <>
[Perfecto-Connect-windows64] $ C:\Perfecto-Connect-windows64\perfectoconnect64.exe start -c demo.perfectomobile.com -s eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICI4YmI4YmZmZS1kMzBjLTQ2MjctYmMxMS0zNTYyMmY1ZDkyMGYifQ.eyJpYXQiOjE2MzM2MDc5MDYsImp0aSI6IjFhOGMwM2RmLTUyMGUtNGIwYi05NjQxLTRmMTdkOWY0YzczYiIsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vYXV0aC5wZXJmZWN0b21vYmlsZS5jb20vYXV0aC9yZWFsbXMvZGVtby1wZXJmZWN0b21vYmlsZS1jb20iLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL2F1dGgucGVyZmVjdG9tb2JpbGUuY29tL2F1dGgvcmVhbG1zL2RlbW8tcGVyZmVjdG9tb2JpbGUtY29tIiwic3ViIjoiZDQyMTczM2MtOTFjOC00YzIxLTgxZmItZmM3OWFlNzRjZmQwIiwidHlwIjoiT2ZmbGluZSIsImF6cCI6Im9mZmxpbmUtdG9rZW4tZ2VuZXJhdG9yIiwibm9uY2UiOiJkY2ZhMDc5Ni05ZWJhLTQxYmYtOThhNi1hODJkMGNlMjAzZWMiLCJzZXNzaW9uX3N0YXRlIjoiYThmNDI0YzktYTM4OC00MmU3LWE3OWUtY2JmNDI1MWRjOWU5Iiwic2NvcGUiOiJvcGVuaWQgb2ZmbGluZV9hY2Nlc3MifQ.azZ-UFTSrrNEVeVUbB7yHjBwd43gJfk3j9zDVAoZ3tI
Tunnel Id : 11b6204e-d69d-4f34-bf2e-1e744b2e18b1
Tunnel Id created succesfully.
Setting Perfecto tunnel id to Environment variable: tunnelId
[Perfecto Scriptless] $ cmd /c call C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\jenkins5026905803885000619.bat

C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins.jenkins\workspace\Perfecto Scriptless>scriptless-cli run --cloudURL "https://demo.app.perfectomobile.com" --securityToken "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICI4YmI4YmZmZS1kMzBjLTQ2MjctYmMxMS0zNTYyMmY1ZDkyMGYifQ.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.azZ-UFTSrrNEVeVUbB7yHjBwd43gJfk3j9zDVAoZ3tI" -p "Salesforce" -v "Base" -j "Salesforce Parallel Job" -l "Chrome 1024x768" -e "https://login.salesforce.com(Default)"
'scriptless-cli' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins.jenkins\workspace\Perfecto Scriptless>exit 9009
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: Either add location of `scriptless-cli` to `PATH` environment variable, so it can be found from anywhere or call it with full path.

Comment: That was the correct answer, I used the where command so I could find the path to the file and after adding the path to the command, it worked as expected. Thanks for help!